# Eloquent on two tables Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables:

**Brand**

```
-----------------
id | name | wheel
-----------------
```

**Wheel**

```
-----------------------------
id |no_of_wheel | brand_wheel
-----------------------------
```

**Brand_Wheel**

```
------------------------
id | brand_id | wheel_id
------------------------
```

I have the following models defined:

```
class brand
{
    public function brandWheel(){
        return $this->hasMany(BrandWheel::class);
    }    
}

class BrandWheel
{
    public function brand(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

I want to get those brands whose wheel_id is 2.

I tired:

```
$brands = Brand::with(['brandWheel' => function($query){
    $query->where('wheel_id','=',2);
}])->get();
```

This code gives me all the brands I have in the table. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The tables are Brand, Wheel and Brand_Wheel.
Their attributes are in the top in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `whereHas` statement. The `with` method will eager load the given relationships. You can find more documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

```
$brands = Brand::with('brandWheel')->whereHas('brandWheel', function($query) {
    $query->where('wheel_id', 2);
})->get();
```

In case you only want Brands that has a brandWheel relationship use `has`. Checkout [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) for more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code get all brands and append to them only brandWheels where wheel_id = 2. You need to use `whereHas()` method.

```
$brands = Brand::with('brandWheel')
    ->whereHas('brandWheel', function($query){
        $query->where('wheel_id', 2)
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Many to Many eloquent relationship described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

So your models should look like:

```
class Brand 
{ 
    public function brandWheels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(BrandWheel::class);
    }    
}

class BrandWheel
{
    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

Notice how I have capitalized your model names since this is the naming convention as defined here https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#3-namespace-and-class-names.

I've also made your relationship names plural, since they are many-to-many, they could return multiple results.

You can now do your query doing something along this line (not tested, might not be 100% accurate):

```
$brands = BrandWheel::find(2)->brands();
```